# Auth::attempt always return false even with proper input

Tags: php, laravel

Here are the facades I used

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
```

I've successfully created user signup page with hashed password using bcrypt.

```
    //Get singnup view
    public function getSignup() 
    {
        return view('user.signup');
    }
    //Process signup
    public function postSignup(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'email|required|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:4'
        ]);
        $user = new User([
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'password' => bcrypt($request->input('password')),
        ]);
        $user->save();
        return redirect()->route('product.index');
    }
```

And now I'm stuck at the signin page. The Auth::attempt always return false. I even tried to store a plain password in my database and signin without bcrypt but it still returned false. I have no idea where I'm wrong right now.

```
//Get signin view
    public function getSignin() 
    {
        return view('user.signin');
    }
    //Process signin
    public function postSignin(Request $request) 
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
                'email' => 'email|required',
                'password' => 'required|min:4'
                ]);
        $credentials = array(
            'email' => $request->input('email'), 
            'password' => bcrypt($request->input('password'))
                );
        if(Auth::attempt($credentials))
        {
            return redirect()->route('user.profile');
        }
        return redirect()->route('product.index');
    }
```

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do? Are you copying the default auth that comes with laravel or create a custom signup/register?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `bcrypt()` in `Auth::attempt()`. Remove it and try again.

Comment: Omg it works :0. Looking back at the documentation, it seems like I misread it. It literally says I should hash the password since the `Auth::attempt` automatically does it.. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score -1):

In `config\auth`, change guard driver setting is set to `api`.

```
'defaults' => [
    'guards' => 'api',
    'passwords' => 'users'
]
```

But Laravel doesn't support `attempt()` function with guard `api`. Thus, you should use some packages like `Passport` (You can reference [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication))

Or simplier, just configure you guard driver with `Auth::guard('api')->attempt($credentials)`

Hope this solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you. But it seems like I don't need to change it to api. I just misread the documentation. It says I shouldn't hash the input password for the `Auth::attempt`. But thanks. I'll note it.